# Проблема с отправкой base64 строки на сервер

Tags: c#, post, base64, byte

Имеется строка после шифрования

> DaNtplGgI/nk3hBys+yYMYIceENnqQDPV/1THS9i6NxBB4aBiXKumPWuztlfNaYt4pOgKEuGger2TUv5su5dWwaGLyGzQrS/X5nfg82HpRvwz4cZlqOV13IDy1bfSjKeuyiDKsYC4fXNBi3vggpvHf4jkdVOYIUladdTRSuGEWA=

Пытаюсь отправить ее на сервер методом POST, но на сервер приходит совсем другая строка. Вот строка которая приходит на сервер.

> nGrJ51VWvB4foOyTrDnBegpyDpY9W/cKNYc3S0TFnuIZGGxOs4YRbbiONQeFKvxYIsxzVLZEtnHSzk8d21AHGcGYcSNFENCxVBy8i2IGDKEzvl5vQ1hcGzzwXMjyoTYsfjkP6DSqSc4PIo2T/S 9zEC3WYzRuyoXhMq/N62RxD4=

При отправке этой строки происходит перевод в byte[] массив, который видимо ее "ломает".

```
byte[] sentData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Data);
req.ContentLength = Data.Length;
Stream sendStream = req.GetRequestStream();
sendStream.Write(sentData, 0, sentData.Length);
sendStream.Close();
```

Как исправить данную проблему?

Comment: А как вы получаете данные на сервере?

Comment: Отправка идет методом POST, соответственно данные хранятся в массиве POST.

Comment: Эээ, а код можно?

Comment: WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(Url);                             req.Method = "POST"; req.Timeout = 100000;
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
byte[] sentData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Data);
req.ContentLength = Data.Length;
Stream sendStream = req.GetRequestStream();
sendStream.Write(sentData, 0, sentData.Length);
sendStream.Close();

Comment: Не, это код отправки, а код получения?

Comment: WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
Stream ReceiveStream = res.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ReceiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);                                                                                Char[] read = new Char[256];
            int count = sr.Read(read, 0, 256);
            string Out = String.Empty;
            while (count > 0)
            {
                String str = new String(read, 0, count);
                Out += str;
                count = sr.Read(read, 0, 256);
            }
            return Out;

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение данной проблемы, изменил отправку запроса. Вот пример кода:

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    var pars = new NameValueCollection();
    pars.Add("message", "CUgUPZxdVGSIT3FzzT9Pc5VfOwKnwZ5fUlSks7hQazk2wJCigOxE3vkuLnIqa8Ab4pLNzdeMsGrV2RgmG4YlMPTfqpOsdkLFwfeqiY/EVrIdbY389eD0oid40JHryosEdHppVkQkpmKYNxhw4VDhbGQ2oTyR0Tk4/KMY/WC63IE=");
    var response = webClient.UploadValues(url, pars);
    string str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
    Console.WriteLine(str);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

После отправки таким способом, приходит та строка, какую отправлял.