# Как обработать POST запрос на сервере с помощью PHP?

Tags: php, c#, visual-studio, post, uwp

Пытаюсь обработать пост запрос отправленный из C# кода. Но до сих пор работающего решения не получилось...

Пробовал делать так:

```
 var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
       {
        { "kod", "111" },
        { "tupe", "0" },
        { "id_user", user.Id },
        { "image", encodedFile }, // файл закодированный в base64
        { "title", "654321" },
        { "text", "1234526" }
       };

        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);
        var content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(String, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://.php", content);

       var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Но в при такой отправке я так и не разобрался как его принять его не сервере. Из-за "application/json".

Далее пробовал так:

```
        var String = "kod=111&tape=0&id_user=" + user.Id + "&image=" + encodedFile + "&title=123&text=dfgdg";
        var content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(String, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://plus-you.ru/mobile/tape_v_2.php", content);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Но теперь при приеме на сервере в закодированном тексте почему-то менялись некоторые символы, что делало невозможным декодировать файл обратно...

Находил множество вариантов с `WebClient` например [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511624/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-base64-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80).
 В моей Visual Studio 2015 почему почему-то `WebClient` вообще не распознается...

Мне нужно либо разобраться как обработать такой Json с помощью PHP на сервере, либо разобраться как отправлять чтобы в base64 не менялись символы, либо какое нибудь еще наставление на путь истинный...

Answer (score 0):

Дело именно в `application/json` (кстати, нашёлся [ещё один подобный вопрос на so](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/262386/213987), поэтому пояснения повторять не буду)

Попробуйте такую связку:

На c# делаете запрос так:

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateHttp("https://server/api/v1/method/");
req.Timeout = 1000 * 60 * 60; /* 1 hour */
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/json";
using (var s = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"{ ""type"": ""demo"", ""name"": ""asdfasdf"" }");
    s.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

using (var res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", res.StatusCode, res.ContentType);
    //Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes:", res.ContentLength);
    using (var s = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
        Console.WriteLine(s.ReadToEnd());
}
```

У вас же практически тоже самое, верно? Нет особой разницы делать это async да и Webclient в этом случае даёт точно такой же запрос, как и у вас.

В реальных приложениях, разумеется строка формируется при помощи Json.Net из заполненного класса с данными.

В PHP обрабатываете так :

```
$handler->Execute(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

И в Execute что-то наподобие:

```
function  Execute($postdata)
{
    try{
        $this->request = json_decode($postdata, true);
```

Переменные `type` и `name` буду видны как `$this->request['type']` и `$this->request['name']`

У меня такая связка давно работает, правда без base64 (не было нужды), насколько именно эта часть вопроса нужна? Полагаю, что когда перейдёте на php://input проблема рассосётся сама собой, но можно и уточнить ответ.

Comment: Мне VS говорит, что HttpWebResponse не содержит GetRequestStream? Есть вариант замены на GetRequestStreamAsync но тогда он пишет: "тип, использованный в оператору using, должен  иметь неявное преобразование  в System.IDisposable...

Comment: И трудности с base64 в том, что при передачи файлов таким образом формируется очень длинная строка.  И не любой способ разрешает такой изврат.

Comment: Я попробовал изменить пока только PHP код, но сервер все равно не видит мои запросы...(

Answer (score 0):

Для `HttpClient`:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;

using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class JsonContent : ByteArrayContent {
    public JsonContent(string content, Encoding encoding) :
        base(GetContentByteArray(content, encoding)) {
        Headers.ContentType =
            new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json") {
                CharSet = encoding.WebName
            };
    }

    protected static byte[] GetContentByteArray(string content, Encoding encoding) {
        return content == null
            ? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(content))
            : encoding.GetBytes(content);
    }
}

public class JsonContent<T> : JsonContent {
    public JsonContent(T content, Encoding encoding)
        : base(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content), encoding) {
    }
}

public static class JsonContentExtensions {
    public static JsonContent ToJsonContent(this object obj, Encoding encoding = null) {
        return new JsonContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj), encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8);
    }
}
```