# Как передать переменную в php с помощью axios

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, axios

Никак не могу разобраться как передать данные собранные с помощью Vue.js в php переменную. Пробовал с помощью axios, но ничего не вышло.

Задача такова: выбираем 2 значения с поля , нажимаем обновить, эти значения передаются в php функцию, там эти значения использую для запроса в БД, потом всё что получил вывожу в html.

Вот код JS:

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  new Vue({
    el: '#all',
    data: {
      items: [],
      selected1: '',
      selected2: '',
    },
    methods: {
      get() {
        axios({
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            url: 'query.php',
            responseType: 'json'
          })
          .then(response => (this.items = (response.data)))
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error)
          });
      }
    },
    mounted() {

    }
  }) <
  /script>
```

Вот так пытаюсь принять на стороне сервера:

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==='POST' && empty($_POST)) {
    $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://php://input'));
    $data = 10;
    $data = $_POST;
}
```

Comment: Может, условие изменть `!empty($_POST)`?

Comment: странно парсить json когда вы передаёте в  x-www-form-urlencoded (я [писал об этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/922388/) в контексте asp.net но пара ссылок оттуда вам пригодится почитать теорию), потому что в urlencode ключ-значения передаются, а не json

Comment: Не вижу, что конкретно отправляется в качестве нагрузки. Вижу метод, вижу заголовки, вижу урл, вижу ещё что-то, а самой нагрузки не вижу. Поля где? :)

Comment: `file_get_contents('http://php://input')` - поправить на `file_get_contents('php://input')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно отправлять не как x-www-form-urlencoded , а как json:

```
const config = {
  baseURL: API_URL,
  headers: {
    post: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  },
};
const instance = axios.create(config);
instance.post('/url', {param1: value1, param2:value2 });
```

Вот [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/922388/) могу порекомендовать пару ссылок для понимания механики:

- [Understanding HTML Form Encoding: URL Encoded and Multipart Forms](https://dev.to/sidthesloth92/understanding-html-form-encoding-url-encoded-and-multipart-forms-3lpa)
- [application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4007969/5752652)

На стороне PHP код у вас правильный, я [похожим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/694108/213987) разбираю:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input")
$json = json_decode($data, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Всем большое спасибо за ответы, всё помогло.

Реализовал так:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#all',
  data: {
    items: '',
    selected1: '',
    selected2: '',
  },
  methods: {
    get() {
      axios({
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          data: {
            sel1: '2',
            sel2: '5',
          },
          url: 'query.php',
          responseType: 'json'
        })
        .then(response => (this.items = response.data))
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error)
        });
    }
  },
})
```

На стороне сервера:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
echo json_encode($data, true);
```

Но ещё появился вопрос, если я на стороне сервера ещё попытаюсь что то вывести, например:

```
data = file_get_contents("php://input");
echo json_encode($data, true);
echo 10;
```

Тогда не выводит совсем ничего (что логично). Как быть в таком случае? В том же ajax эту проблему решить легко.